# Can I apply a rule of inference within an argument expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm brand new to discrete math, and I'm trying to prove the following argument:

\begin{align}
& p \rightarrow (q \land r)  \\
&\lnot q \\
&\overline{\therefore \lnot p}
\end{align}
The law of Simplification states:
\begin{align}
&p \land q \\
&\overline{\therefore p}
\end{align}
As a first step, can I use the simplification rule to simplify $p \rightarrow (q \land r)$ to $p \rightarrow q$? Is it always/sometimes permissible to apply a law of inference *within* a statement like this, or do I need be able to apply it to a complete, stand-alone statement (can I ONLY safely simplify something like $q \land r$ alone)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As a first step, can I use the simplification rule to simplify $p→(q∧r)$ to $p→q$?

Not *as the first* step, no.   The first step would be to assume $p$, then you eliminate the conditional, and *after* that can you apply simplification (conjunction elimination).

> Is it always/sometimes permissible to apply a law of inference within a statement like this, …

It is *never* permisable to apply a rule of inference to *part* of a statement.

> … or do I need be able to apply it to a complete, stand-alone statement (can I ONLY safely simplify something like $q∧r$ alone)?

Yes, rules of inference are applied to whole statements, and the root connective.

---

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[p]^1\quad p\to(q\land r)}{q\land r}{\lnot\!E}}{q}{\land E}\quad\lower{1.5ex}{ \lnot q}~~}{\phantom\bot}{\phantom{\lnot E}}}{\phantom{\lnot p}}{\phantom{\lnot I^1}}$$

Comment: Am I allowed to assume $p$ here? From what I gathered so far, I assume the hypotheses $p \rightarrow (q \land r)$ and $\lnot q$ are true, but I didn't think I could assume $p$ right off the bat.

Comment: You may assume anything for sake of argument, as long as it is properly discharged.  Here you assume $p$ aiming to derive a contradiction, and thus deducing the result when properly discharged.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $p\land q=p$ only if $p=q=$ True

Similarly, $p\rightarrow(q\land r)=p\rightarrow q$ only if $q=r=$ True

Answer (score 0):

While you can apply rules of *equivalence* to subexpressions, you are *not* allowed to do this for rules of *inference*, and that is because you can end up making invalid inferences if you do. Example:

Suppose you try to apply $\land$ Elim to go from

$$(P \land Q) \to R$$

To

$$P \to R$$

Well, with $P$ being True, and $Q$ and $R$ False, you'll find that $(P \land Q) \to R$ is True, but $P \to R$ is False. So this is an invalid inference.