# Why can't I apply a rule of inference within an argument expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252514/can-i-apply-a-rule-of-inference-within-an-argument-expression) tells me I cannot apply inference rules to subexpressions. But why can't I? Do I run the risk of making an incorrect inference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, applying a rule of inference to a subexpression indeed runs the risk of making an invalid inference.

Example. Suppose you use $\land$ Elim to do:

$$(P \land Q) \to R$$

$$\therefore P \to R$$

Well, that is invalid. With $P$ True and $Q$ and $R$ both false, you have that $(P \land Q) \to R$ is True, but $P \to R$ is False.

Comment: ok, an inference on a subexpression leads in this case to an invalid transformation. Is there a general proof of why inference rules cannot be used in subexpressions?

Comment: For classical representations it’s hard to come up with a general rule for when weakening or strengthening would be valid ... it can be done, but you’d need to count negations and conditionals. So, to avoid any possible problems, most systems will simply disallow inference rules to be applied to subexpressions, period. However, for a system where weakening and strengthening can be accounted for much more easily, see Existential Graphs

Answer (score 2):

In the linked question, suppose you apply the rule of simplification $$\begin{align}
&q \land r \\
&\overline{\therefore r}
\end{align}$$
To simplify $p \rightarrow (q \land r)$ to $p\rightarrow r$.  Obviously from $p\rightarrow r$ and $\lnot q$ we cannot deduce $\lnot p$ ($p$ and $r$ may be true and $q$ false,) so we erroneously conclude that the theorem is false.